# db password leak to logs

Tags: sqlalchemy, airflow

I configured Airflow metadata db as MySQL.

```
 sql_alchemy_conn = sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
```

After that I used `initdb` command:

```
airflow initdb
```

Tables in the airflow db have been created.

Then I runed command:

```
airflow shceduler
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

in logs:

```
[2020-01-14 18:39:03,457: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
```

password as plain text.

How can I turn off that? Is sql_alchemy log? It's password leak to logs.

Comment: One option could be to encrypt the logs.

Comment: Could be, but it is not a solution by design.

Comment: Agreed; better than nothing, and also better than not logging. Took a quick look at the airflow docs and saw that it was one of the built-in features.

Comment: In this case - logs are used by another tools, they cannot be encrypted.

Comment: Doesn't look like the normal logs that SQLA produces.

Comment: I think the log statement might be coming from the celery worker (https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/worker/consumer/connection.py#L24)?